# Graph Error or Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>)

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, jupyter, 3d-convolution

I have been trying to solve this issue for the last few weeks but is unable to figure it out. I am hoping someone out here could help out.

I am following this github repository for generating a model for lip reading however everytime I try to train my own version of the model I get this error: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>). I have already tried several solutions posted online from changing my libraries versions, etc.

Here is the repo: https://github.com/nicknochnack/LipNet/blob/main/LipNet.ipynb

I cant seem to complete 1 epoch before getting the said error.

Here is my code so far:

```
import os
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from typing import List
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import imageio
import gdown
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D, LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Bidirectional, MaxPool3D, Activation, Reshape, SpatialDropout3D, BatchNormalization, TimeDistributed, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler

url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1YlvpDLix3S-U8fd-gqRwPcWXAXm8JwjL'
output = 'data.zip'
gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)
gdown.extractall('data.zip')

def load_video(path:str) -> List[float]: 

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
    frames = []
    for _ in range(int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))): 
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(frame)
        frames.append(frame[190:236,80:220,:])
    cap.release()
    
    mean = tf.math.reduce_mean(frames)
    std = tf.math.reduce_std(tf.cast(frames, tf.float32))
    return tf.cast((frames - mean), tf.float32) / std
vocab = [x for x in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'?!123456789 "]
char_to_num = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab, oov_token="")
num_to_char = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=char_to_num.get_vocabulary(), oov_token="", invert=True
)

print(
    f"The vocabulary is: {char_to_num.get_vocabulary()} "
    f"(size ={char_to_num.vocabulary_size()})"
)
char_to_num.get_vocabulary()
def load_alignments(path:str) -> List[str]: 
    with open(path, 'r') as f: 
        lines = f.readlines() 
    tokens = []
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split()
        if line[2] != 'sil': 
            tokens = [*tokens,' ',line[2]]
    return char_to_num(tf.reshape(tf.strings.unicode_split(tokens, input_encoding='UTF-8'), (-1)))[1:]
def load_data(path: str): 
    path = bytes.decode(path.numpy())
    #file_name = path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    # File name splitting for windows
    file_name = path.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]
    video_path = os.path.join('data','s1',f'{file_name}.mpg')
    alignment_path = os.path.join('data','alignments','s1',f'{file_name}.align')
    frames = load_video(video_path) 
    alignments = load_alignments(alignment_path)
    
    return frames, alignments

test_path = '.\\data\\s1\\bbal6n.mpg'
tf.convert_to_tensor(test_path).numpy().decode('utf-8').split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]
frames, alignments = load_data(tf.convert_to_tensor(test_path))
tf.strings.reduce_join([bytes.decode(x) for x in num_to_char(alignments.numpy()).numpy()])

def mappable_function(path:str) ->List[str]:
    result = tf.py_function(load_data, [path], (tf.float32, tf.int64))
    return result

data = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('./data/s1/*.mpg')
data = data.shuffle(500, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
data = data.map(mappable_function)
data = data.padded_batch(2, padded_shapes=([75,None,None,None],[40]))
data = data.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
# Added for split 
train = data.take(450)
test = data.skip(450)

frames, alignments = data.as_numpy_iterator().next()

sample = data.as_numpy_iterator()

val = sample.next(); val[0]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(128, 3, input_shape=(75,46,140,1), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool3D((1,2,2)))

model.add(Conv3D(256, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool3D((1,2,2)))

model.add(Conv3D(75, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool3D((1,2,2)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, kernel_initializer='Orthogonal', return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(.5))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, kernel_initializer='Orthogonal', return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(.5))

model.add(Dense(char_to_num.vocabulary_size()+1, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

yhat = model.predict(val[0])

def scheduler(epoch, lr):
    if epoch < 30:
        return lr
    else:
        return lr * tf.math.exp(-0.1)

def CTCLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
    input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
    label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")

    input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
    label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")

    loss = tf.keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
    return loss

class ProduceExample(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback): 
    def __init__(self, dataset) -> None: 
        self.dataset = dataset.as_numpy_iterator()
    
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None) -> None:
        data = self.dataset.next()
        yhat = self.model.predict(data[0])
        decoded = tf.keras.backend.ctc_decode(yhat, [75,75], greedy=False)[0][0].numpy()
        for x in range(len(yhat)):           
            print('Original:', tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(data[1][x])).numpy().decode('utf-8'))
            print('Prediction:', tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(decoded[x])).numpy().decode('utf-8'))
            print('~'*100)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss=CTCLoss)

checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join('models','checkpoint'), monitor='loss', save_weights_only=True) 
example_callback = ProduceExample(test)
schedule_callback = LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)

model.fit(train, validation_data=test, epochs=100, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback, schedule_callback, example_callback])
```

Comment: The full traceback would be helpful. I suspect a problem with paths, and videos not being read because of that. OpenCV loves to fail silently, so check that you actually get an image and not `None` out of the reading functions.

Comment: Yeah I went ahead and created an if statement for the frame (to check if its empty and continue) and I got it to work eventually (after many more other errors).

Answer (score 1):

To those who are having the same problem. The solution I found and used was to create an if else statement for the frame variable. OpenCV seems to fail in reading from video frames from time to time.

Here is the code that worked for me.

```
def load_video(path:str) -> List[float]: 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
frames = []
missing_frames = []
for _ in range(int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if frame is None:
        missing_frames.append(frame)
        continue
        
    frame = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(frame)
    frames.append(frame[190:236,80:220,:])
cap.release()

mean = tf.math.reduce_mean(frames)
std = tf.math.reduce_std(tf.cast(frames, tf.float32))
return tf.cast((frames - mean), tf.float32) / std
```